# Text indentation in the shape of an arc

Tags: css

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this via CSS? The idea is to shape text like an Arc.

Thanks!

```css
#p1 {
  text-indent: 0;
}
#p2 {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
#p3 {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
#p4 {
  text-indent: 30px;
}
#p5 {
  text-indent: 40px;
}
#p6 {
  text-indent: 30px;
}
#p7 {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
#p8 {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
#p9 {
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: Your example shows more a triangular shape than an arc, so I would go with caramba's solution (nested margin) that should work across all browsers, Dale's solution is very nice if you want really achieve arc and you get much cleaner html, but you'll have to bother with FF not mentioning IE/Edge

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want a perfect arc you can use `shape-outside` to create a circle or ellipse that the text will follow.

You can see how this works [image: circle]

However support is [spotty](https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside) to say the least.

```css
div{
    shape-outside: circle(50%);
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
<span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</span>
```

Comment: That's awesome, however, it's not supported on EDGE, IE, Firefox and Opera. :/
https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside

Comment: That's true, I just finished updating my answer to say as much. @odedta

Comment: Yeah, well, that deserves an up-vote nevertheless! thanks :-)

Comment: Here's a polyfill: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill

Comment: I have to accept this answer in the lack of a better supported answer. Thank you very much Dale!

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the same result with one class and one rule on that class. The trick is to repeat the elements inside each other:

```css
.blubb {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blubb">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <div class="blubb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      <div class="blubb">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          <div class="blubb">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            <div class="blubb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="blubb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blubb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blubb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
<div class="blubb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Comment: Hah, neat! that's a nice way :-)

Comment: @odedta what do you mean? what should be different?

Answer (score 3):

As Dale said, use shape-outside for a pure css solution. However due to browser support we have to find a lower-level solution.

Contains comments for non-jQuery solution, code contains jQuery.

```js
var ps = 9;//paragraphs
var i = 1;//start id
var x = 0;//left position
var amount = 50;
for(i=1;i<ps;i++){
 //calculate left position in arc
  //(i/ps) gets value between 0 and 1, Math.PI is to make it radians for sine, *amount is max indent
  //bearing in mind this bit can be changed to give more desired effect.
  x = Math.sin(((i-1)/(ps-1))*Math.PI)*amount;
  
  //get element using jquery and set its text-indent to x
  //otherwise you could use document.getElementById('p'+i); and textIndent JS property if you dont want jQuery.
  $('#p'+i).css('text-indent', x+'px');
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p id="p9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```